# How to retrieve entity with column of database type text[] and not get NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipselink

I have an entity that is defined as per below, when I try to retrieve it from the database it throw and intermitent `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`. The Error normally occurs when that endpoint is called multiple times before the other finishes. From my experience and internet search, this error usually occurs when the compiled java version does not match the runtime java version.

I am using Java 8 for compiling and running the application. I am also using Eclipselink 2.6.2 and the Postgres driver version is 42.3.3.

**Entity:**

```
@Struct(name = "myArrayColumn")
@Entity
@Table(name = "myTable")
public class MyTableEntity {
    ...
    @Column(name = "myArrayColumn", columnDefinition = "text[]")
    @Array(databaseType = "varchar")
    private List<String> myArrayColumn;
    ...
}
```

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
...
  myArrayColumn    text[],
...
)
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.ByteBuffer.position(I)Ljava\/nio\/ByteBuffer;
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.ArrayDecoding.readBinaryArray(ArrayDecoding.java:529)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.readBinaryArray(PgArray.java:175)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.getArrayImpl(PgArray.java:150)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.getArray(PgArray.java:111)
```

Comment: Hmm, this is a class/method from the JDK not in the JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes, and the weird part is that the error is intermittent and the application is running in openshift containers

Comment: You might try using the latest driver version (42.5.0?) for java 8. You mentioned calling an endpoint, but not the container running this. If all sources suggest a versioning issue, check that your container doesn't have multiple jars on the class path. Remove duplicates where ever possible so that class loaders can't take different paths and cause this.  When this occurs, do the other processes continue to work, or does this require intervention (like a restart) to fix?

Answer (score -2):

You are in the wrong thinking. The database does not support storing this kind of array object. You can store multiple records and use a column to associate them, or store them as sentences separated by special symbols, and then use the String.split function to split them after taking them out.

Comment: Postgres **does** support [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html)

Comment: Check out https://itnext.io/how-to-map-postgresql-array-type-to-list-using-jpa-and-eclipselink-b4e25ca13490 and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html

Comment: Thanks. Seems it's a new feature!